# Carport condensation issue

Tags: condensation, carport

Recently, my carport started to collect condensation when it's warm after a cold night.  This never happened before.  Carport is attached to the sun-room.  The change that was made to it is enclosing the screened in porch and making a sun-room out of it.

I was wondering if there is anything that could be the cause this condensation and how it could be fixed?  I appreciate any advice!

[image: Bottom View]
[image: Side View]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: You state you made a sun room out of your carport ? Just making certain we are on the same page.

Here is your problem : Before you enclosed the carport it was exposed to the outside temperatures just like the roof was, now that it is enclosed you have a temperature differential. It is warmer on the underside than it is on the top side. Insulate the roof / ceiling and you should not have the problem any more.